# Size of a Java Object that contains only primitive types

Tags: java, object, sizeof, primitive, unsafe

I have a class that is consisted of the following primitive types only:

```
public class Test{

private int a1; //size of int =4
private long a2; //size of long = 8
private double a3[]; //size of double =8

}
```

Moreover, I have an object for this class like this:

```
Test test= new Test(1,3,new double[] {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4});
```

I would like to have a function that will find the size of this object and in this case it would return 4 + 8 + 4*8 = 44.

Comment: I am not interested in the total size of the object, but only at the total size of the primitive variables being used as showed in the example given.

Comment: Then ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: http://btoddb-java-sizing.blogspot.com/ for sizes on a 64-bit JVM; a 32-bit JVM uses 4-byte memory alignment instead of 8-byte memory alignment, so ints and floats would take up 4 bytes instead of 8

Comment: (Your object takes more than 44 bytes in practice; assuming a 32-bit HotSpot VM, your `double[]` is actually a 4-byte reference to an array object, which has an 8-byte header, a 4-byte length field, and _then_ your four double objects, so 60 is probably a more accurate number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, then it is something you could have easily implemented yourself, but here we go:

```
public class Test {
    private int a1;
    private long a2;
    private double a3[];

    public Test(final int a1, final long a2, final double[] a3) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return 4 + 8 + (a3.length * 8);
    }
}
```

Also a few notes:

- Refrain from using `Test` as classname, you should use something like `SizeTest` or whatever, but simply test will eventually cause havoc if you would decide to unit test it or whatnot.
- Give variables meaningful names. If I had the oppurtunity I would've done so, but I can really cannot make anything from the current names.

If you are looking for a generic function, then well things turn a lot harder, in that case you would be looking for a method with the followed signature: `SizeTester.getSize(Object object);`, it is still doable, but you would need to use Reflection then to get information about the fields and you should only use that if absolutely neccessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but obviously I am searching for a generic function.

Comment: Finally, I am calculating the size manually by using a hashMap where i store the different sizes for each type and moreover array.length*type_size for the size of the array. Thanks a lot again.